# php file problem error showing by vscode extension named php intellisense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOhwB.png)

I have been facing this problem for a long time while using the extension for the PHP file, I always see this error about some kind of deprecation, didn't find any solution yet, it's very annoying actually.

tried solving by:

1. reinstalling vscode
2. uninstall then install the extension again,
3. while used in other IDE, it works just fine

the file works but, don't know what's the error

Comment: wich PHP version are you using?

Comment: php 8.0.0 is being used